# Django Aggregation - output field not working as expected

Tags: django, aggregate

```
Book.objects.aggregate(price_diff=Max('price', output_field=FloatField()) - Avg('price'))
```

Error : Expression contains mixed types: FloatField, De
cimalField. You must set output_field.

Even though output filed used

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this should be

```python
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, FloatField, Max

Book.objects.aggregate(
    ExpressionWrapper(
        price_diff=Max(F("price")) - Avg(F("price")), output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations